# ActivityManager visibility in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, memory-management

I am trying to use the ActivityManager class to get memory usage statistics of bunch of processes using getMemoryInfo(pids[]). But looks like eclipse is not allowing me instantiate an object for ActivityManager. I'm getting error - ActivityManager() is not visible

Any help is highly appreciated. 
Thanks,
ghatotkach

Comment: Check out http://androidforums.com/application-development/1413-create-object-activitymanager.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not create an instance of `ActivityManager`. You obtain an instance via a call to  `getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE)` from your `Activity` or `Service`.